# Как понимать смысл параллельных синтаксических конструкций: была издана, издана?

Tags: связка

У Розенталя о параллельных синтаксических конструкциях написано:

Различие между сочетаниями книга издана и книга была издана заключается не в большей или меньшей отдаленности во времени (ср.: книга была издана в прошлом году – книга издана в XVII веке, где связка была отнюдь не вносит значения большей давности), а в том, что при отсутствии связки имеется в виду наличие результата в настоящем, при наличии связки – отнесение результата к прошлому; ср.: «Мертвые души» написаны Гоголем. – Второй том «Мертвых душ» был написан Гоголем (но сожжен); «Евгений Онегин» написан Пушкиным. – Десятая глава «Евгения Онегина» была написана Пушкиным (но не издана).

Я не совсем понимаю, что значит "наличие результата в настоящем" и "отнесение результата к прошлому".

Например, такое предложение:

В свою очередь, министр иностранных дел России Сергей Лавров заявил, что в Лозанне были достигнуты принципиальные договоренности по всем ключевым вопросам.

Можно ли опустить "были"?

Есть ли здесь "наличие результата в настоящем" или "отнесение результата к прошлому"?

Или такое предложение:

Двери были неплотно затворены, Маша подходит на цыпочках и смотрит в них потихоньку.

Здесь нужно обязательно писать "были", так как двери закрыли до того, как Маша подошла?

Но ведь, с другой стороны, вроде есть "наличие результата в настоящем": вот они неплотно затворенные двери.

Если сравнить два предложения:

В рамках экономико-социологического подхода были проанализированы связи миграции с сезонными перемещениями.

и

В рамках экономико-социологического подхода проанализированы миграции с сезонными перемещениями.

то в чем смысловая разница между ними?

"Наличие результата в настоящем" есть в первом и ее нет во втором?

Comment: @doom, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В первой фразе "настоящее" нужно трактовать как момент её произнесения. Если речь о только что произошедших переговорах, можно опустить "были" (ситуация только что изменилась - сейчас важна новость). С "были" выражение более универсально, оно может говорить как о последних событиях, так и о событиях недавнего прошлого, о которых ещё не говорилось.

Во фразе про Машу:
Здесь имеет место повествовательный приём перенесения в настоящее время событий прошлого ("Маша подходит"), поэтому "были" использовано для обозначения момента, предшествующего "перенесённому в настоящее". Но я бы не стал утверждать, что иначе нельзя: речь может идти не о том, что до того кто-то неплотно закрыл двери, а состоянии дверей в тот же самый момент. Это вопрос стиля - можно и так рассказывать: "просыпаюсь я, двери неплотно закрыты, подходит к ним Маша..."

были проанализированы - рассказ о том, что делалось на мероприятии - возможно, с тех пор прошёл какой-то период времени

проанализированы - акцент на результат недавнего события: этот результат актуален и сейчас (когда об этом говорится)

Answer (score 1):

В предложениях ''Книга была издана в прошлом году'' - ''Книга издана в XVII веке, краткое страдательное причастие без связки может также выражать действие, относящиеся к истекшему периоду времени.В этом случае оно равно по значению краткому страдательному причастию со связкой ***был.*** ***(Действие, совершившееся в истекшем отрезке времени).***
В примерах   ***''Мертвые души'' написаны Гоголем''. -  Второй том ''Мертвых душ'' был написан Гоголем (но сожжен); ''Евгений Онегин'' написан Пушкиным''. - Десятая глава ''Евгения Онегина'' была написана Пушкиным (но не издана).*** Краткое страдательное причастие без связки  указывает на состояние как результат действия. Во втором примере краткое страдательное причастие со связкой ''был''указывает на состояние, в котором находилась книга( т.е. она была не издана, осталась на черновиках).
Аналогично в примере: ***Двери были неплотно затворены, Маша подходит на цыпочках и смотрит в них потихоньку.*** Страдательное причастие указывает на состояние, в котором находились двери, в момент, когда Маша подошла к дверям. В этом примере говорится о ситуации, которая  имела место в прошлом.

А в примерах ***''В рамках экономико-социологического подхода были проанализированы связи миграции с сезонными перемещениями.'' и    ''В рамках экономико-социологического подхода проанализированы миграции с сезонными перемещениями''.*** возможны оба варианта. Краткое страдательное причастие без связки, как уже отмечалось выше,может также выражать действие, относящиеся к истекшему периоду времени.

Важно при этом отметить, что краткое страдательное причастие  можно употребить и тогда, когда речь идет о состояние в настоящем времени.
***Ср.: Дверь открыта. Дверь была открыта. В первом предложении СИС указывает на состояние, в котором находится дверь в настоящее время.***

***Во втором примере СИС выражает состояние, в котором находилась дверь в определенный момент в прошлом.***

Answer (score 1):

```
  что значит "наличие результата в настоящем" и "отнесение результата к прошлому".
```

doom,Розенталь данными примерами иллюстрировал положение о верном употреблении времени причастий: "При прошедшем времени глагола-сказуемого причастие настоящего времени указывает на постоянный признак, причастие прошедшего времени – на временный признак. Например: Нас заинтересовал домик, стоящий на опушке леса (ср.:...который стоит...). – Артем схватил тяжелый молот, стоявший у наковальни... (Н. Островский) (ср.: ...который стоял...)." http://www.irbis.vegu.ru/repos/12073/HTML/214.htm

Такое же соответствие и в составном именном сказуемом, где причастие в прошедшем времени,а глагольная связка настоящего, прош. или буд. врем. указывает на временнОе соответствие данной реалии моменту речи.Если связка нулевая - наст. время: это реально есть сейчас, постоянный признак(издана и существует сейчас); если в прош. времени - это было в прошлом, но вовсе не обязательно есть сейчас , непостоянный признак; в буд. вр.- событие ирреально, "книга будет издана".

В свою очередь, министр иностранных дел России Сергей Лавров заявил, что в Лозанне были достигнуты принципиальные договоренности по всем ключевым вопросам.- были достигнуты, но действуют ли сейчас? Я тоже сомневаюсь вместе с Лавровым, поэтому не стоит убирать связку, что-то не вижу постоянности этой реальности. Правда, в контексте высказывания связка "были" необходима для УТВЕРЖДЕНИЯ, что ТОГДА это произошло, это было как факт, хотя и только по ключевым вопросам.И нужно укрепить это, иначе договорённости не будут иметь значения.-постоянности здесь нет.

Двери были неплотно затворены, Маша подходит на цыпочках и смотрит в них потихоньку.Разнобой времён вполне обоснован. В первом предложении всё по норме - непостоянный признак, а второе предложение с помощью худ. приёма - употребления глагола наст. времени в значении прош.- автор как бы помещает читателя в то время. Возможно было бы применить приём и в первом предложении,но тогда мы бы наблюдали и за дверью, а автору важно приковать наше внимание к Маше.

В рамках экономико-социологического подхода были проанализированы связи миграции с сезонными перемещениями.- событие прошлого, неизвестно, актуален ли этот анализ сейчас, это непостоянный признак.

В рамках экономико-социологического подхода проанализированы связи миграции с сезонными перемещениями.-настоящее время, признак постоянный: связи проанализированы и важны для настоящего.

Так что смысловая разница есть

Comment: 

 http://www.irbis.vegu.ru/repos/12073/HTML/214.htm

Comment: Людмила, ваши объяснения отчасти правильны. Но нулевая связка с кратким страдательным причастием может также выражать действие, относящиеся к истекшему периоду времени..В этом случае оно равно по значению краткому страдательному причастию со связкой был. 

Ср.: Московский университет основан (был основан) в 1755. Товары осмотрены( были осмотрены) вчера. И в чем разница?

Comment: Всё равно есть разница в акцентах -Московский университет основан  в 1755. -акцент на постоянный признак: с давних пор  стоит и стоять будет. Был основан - акцент на дате, а потом должен быть рассказ о том, что там менялось со дня основания, иначе форма прош. времени будет неоправданной. Товары осмотрены вчера -нужен контекст. Осмотрены, всё в порядке и сейчас, или что-то, что выявлено,актуально и сегодня.Товары были осмотрены  вчера -  смысл, что работа уже выполнена и к ней не надо возвращаться, это неактуально. Или:...осмотрены вчера, а за ночь что-то изменилось, обнаружилось что-то.

Comment: Людмила, примере взяты из книги ''Грамматика английского языка''.К. Н. Качалова, Е. Е Израилевич. Там в теме ''Пассивный залог'' объясняется конструкции залога и способы их перевода на русский язык. Именно там и говорится,что ''Краткие страдательные причастия без связки могут выражать действие,относящиеся к истекшему периоду времени''. В качестве примеров даются те примеры, которые я привел.

Comment: Кстати, о результате, в котором вы так сомневаетесь, говорится именно в той ссылке, которую привели вы.

Comment: Одно другому не мешает. Я объясняла непонятое у Розенталя, там всё понятно и корректно. А насчёт фразы Лаврова - нужен весь контекст. И слово "были" там никак нельзя убрать, потому что оппоненты как раз утверждали, что много разногласий, нужны ещё встречи, чтобы что-то решить и достигнуть согласия по вопросам  срока ограничений, санкций и невыполнения договорённостей. Я как раз об этом и говорила(сомневалась в выполнении), а для Лаврова важно, что хоть и не по всем, а только по ключевым вопросам, но соглашения были достигнуты, так что и у него есть сомнение в окончательной договорённости.

Answer (score 0):

Попробую привести рассуждение пользователя языка исходя  только из здравого смысла, а не из учебников (задача как бы еще не решена)

1) Отсутствие глагольной связки БЫЛО говорит о том, что действие завершилось: а) к настоящему моменту времени; б) говорящему неизвестно, когда именно, есть только результат; в) рассматривается только  факт завершенного действия без отношения ко времени (этот роман написан писателем N, но: этот роман был написан в 1825 году).

2) Наличие глагольной связки БЫЛО говорит о том,что действие завершилось к определенному моменту в прошлом и **говорящему об этом известно**.

Примеры

1) "В свою очередь, министр иностранных дел России Сергей Лавров заявил, что в Лозанне были достигнуты принципиальные договоренности по всем ключевым вопросам". Связку опустить нельзя, если между моментом речи и событием явно присутствует временной промежуток.

2)"Двери были неплотно затворены, Маша подходит на цыпочках и смотрит в них потихоньку". Предложение мне не кажется удачным. Художественный прием присутствия в прошлом следует применить уже к первому предложению: "Двери  неплотно затворены, Маша подходит на цыпочках и смотрит в них потихоньку".

3) В рамках экономико-социологического подхода были проанализированы связи миграции с сезонными перемещениями. Обе формы возможны, надо знать, откуда взят текст (в этой работе проанализированы результаты - к моменту написания работы были проанализированы результаты).

4) Еще пример. На стене таблица: "Станция открыта 27 декабря 2005 года". Её повесили в день открытия. Но если мы будем рассказывать историю метрополитена, то надо будет сказать, что станция была открыта 27 декабря 2005 года.