# СИС с кратким страдательным причастием

Tags: грамматика, семантика, сказуемые, причастия, краткое-причастие

1. *Храм построен в XIX веке французскими архитекторами*.
2. *Храм был построен в XIX веке французскими архитекторами*.

Никогда не понимал, в чём разница? И там и там страдательное причастие прошедшего времени. Только во втором случае указывается время, но семантика прошедшего времени уже заложена в самом причастии.

Моё предположение такое. В Предложении 1 указывается качество храма, которое заключается в том, что его построили французские архитекторы в XIX веке. В Предложении 2 утверждается факт постройки храма французскими архитекторами в XIX веке.

**Дополнение**

Прошу прощения, подобный вопрос уже есть на сайте: [Как понимать смысл параллельных синтаксических конструкций: была издана, издана?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/49096/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Розенталь:
Различие между сочетаниями *книга издана* и *книга была издана* заключается не в большей или меньшей отдаленности во времени (ср.: *книга была издана в прошлом году – книга издана в XVII веке*, где связка была отнюдь не вносит значения большей давности), а в том, что при отсутствии связки имеется в виду наличие результата в настоящем, при наличии связки – отнесение результата к прошлому; ср.:
*«Мертвые души» написаны Гоголем.

Второй том «Мертвых душ» был написан Гоголем (но сожжен).*

*«Евгений Онегин» написан Пушкиным.

Десятая глава «Евгения Онегина» была написана Пушкиным (но не издана).*

Answer (score 2):

Глагол "быть" в русском необязателен, в отличие от английского. Но тут его добавление звучит. Казалось бы, что это одно и то же, но нет.

*Построен* — просто факт постройки, а результат на данный момент.
*Крепость построена из белого камня – ракушечника.* || И мы видим этот материал в данный момент.

*Был построен* — сопоставимо со "строился", оттенок процесса постройки (*было построение*), а результат может относиться к моменту постройки.
*Ученые рассказали, как был построен Стоунхендж.* || Тут явно значение процесса — как строился тогда, а не как построен сейчас.

*Был построен* — есть коннотация, что уже не сохранился или что не сохранился первоначальный вид постройки.

Ещё употребляется структура: *был построен* + *для чего-то*.

Становится более понятно, если посмотреть разницу на английском языке:
*The temple is built.

The temple was built.*

Comment: Только вот на английском не скажешь: The temple is built in the XIX century, а на русском можно.

Comment: "*А вам не кажется, что указания времени постройки «в XIX веке» при настоящем времени сказуемого «построен» вообще быть не может*" — согласен. По Розенталю, дата указывает на результат в прошедшем времени. Даже место указывает на момент в прошлом (в Лозане были достигнуты, а не сейчас там достигнуты). Но в плане звучания отсутствие связки не критично, а ориентируются больше на него. Но проблема ещё в смысловом диссонансе: был построен ещё воспринимается как построен тогда, а уже разрушен (но это не имеется в виду).

Comment: Место необязательно указывает на момент в прошлом. Сообщение в новостях: «В городе X подорван мост».

Comment: Не уверен, что всегда, но даже тут указывает. "Подорван" используется для описания короткого момента (взрыва) в прошлом. Нельзя сказать, что он подорван на данный момент, в отличие от написан. Возможно, что эта особенность игнорируется, так как является менее существенной, чем дата, которая тоже игнорируется. А то, что популярно, в лингвистике превращается из ошибки в норму.

Comment: *Нельзя сказать, что он подорван на данный момент* — как раз таки можно. Да, взрыв произошёл в определённый момент в прошлом, но предложение говорит о результате в настоящий момент, о факте на данный момент.

Comment: Просто это такой глагол, который ощущается как что-то очень короткое. Не говорят, что он сейчас взорван. Это больше действие в прошлом, а не качество в данный момент. С "разрушен" уже нет такого: *но сейчас уже здание разрушено*.

Comment: Хорошо, «В городе X разрушен мост». Указание места говорит о том, что результат в прошедшем времени?

Comment: Так уже лучше воспринимается. Здесь разные факторы. Почему-то каждый пример индивидуально анализируется. Нет однозначности. Розенталь рассмотрел основной фактор, больше относящийся к его примерам. Жаль, что так мало о такой спорной теме.

Comment: Не стоит рассматривать только результат. В этом плане "*храм построен в XIX веке*" тоже обозначает, что мы видим храм как теперешний результат построения в том веке.

Comment: Но обстоятельство относится к сказуемому, а сказуемое наше обозначает результат. Так что рассматривать стоит именно результат. В городе X наблюдается результат — разрушенный мост. Правда в некоторых ситуациях этот принцип притягивается за уши. *«Мертвые души» написаны Гоголем* — в настоящий момент мы видим результат, авторство Гоголя.

Comment: Рассматривать результат стоит всегда, но не только лишь его (а всё, что можно заметить при анализе). Авторство Гоголя - это не результат (такой результат можно во всём найти), результат - само произведение, которое можно почитать. И разница есть. *В городе X разрушен мост* - стоит разрушенный мост как факт. *В городе X был разрушен мост* - было действие разрушения моста. А в новостях, скорее всего, хотят сообщить о том, что его раньше разрушили, а не о факте, что он сейчас разрушен (без комментариев), так что не пытайтесь по нём перебраться.

Comment: Нет, для предложения *«Мертвые души» написаны Гоголем* результат заключается как раз в том, что Гоголь — автор произведения, что он написал данное произведение. Именно этот результат передаёт сказуемое «написаны». Но согласен с вами в том, что помимо результата в предложении также косвенно указывается факт действия, которое было совершено в прошлом. Однако первостепенную роль в семантике предложения играет именно результат, который заключается в авторстве Гоголя («Мертвых душ»), в состоянии разрушенности (моста), в факте постройки (храма).

Comment: Нет-нет. Здесь надо смотреть не на результат по словам, а на практический (смысловой, исходящий из предложения), как в Present Perfect. То есть написаны - можем почитать, а были написаны, но не сохранились (результата уже нет, но Гоголь автором в любом случае остаётся) - почитать уже никак не можем. А "первостепенная роль" в основном определяется контекстом (если возможны варианты).

Comment: Я заметил, что вы часто проводите параллели с английскими временами. Это не совсем верно, в частности в случае с вашим сравнением нашего СИС со страдательным причастием и Present Perfect. Это время на русский может переводиться и как «написан», и как «был написан» в зависимости от ситуации. Так что такой параллелизм неправомерен.

Comment: Это не параллелизм, а аналогия (похожее). Аналогии (по методике) способствуют пониманию. И результат не в состоянии разрушенности моста. Он в том, что мостом сейчас не получится воспользоваться, он нуждается в восстановлении, так что нужно искать другой путь. Результат более широкий. Его подсознательно закладывает автор. *Это оружие сделано из хромированной стали* - результат в том, что его трудно сломать [сейчас].

Comment: "*Это время на русский может переводиться...*" — это связано с нестрогостью норм, которые мы здесь обсуждаем. Корректнее переводить так, как оно в английском. А там всё чётко, так что понять проще, поэтому и решил провести эту аналогию в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Каждое предложение существует **не само по себе, а в каком-то контексте,** и это обязательно надо учитывать.

**1)  Храм построен** . Краткое причастие обозначает простую завершенность действия без привязки к другим событиям.

Эта форма используется, если нужно сообщить какие-то детали строительства (когда, где, кем, на чьи средства и т.д.), но при этом сообщение  не связано  временными отношениями с другими событиями, которые описаны в тексте. 
В этом случае форма "храм был построен" также может использоваться.

**2) Храм был построен**

Связка используется, если существует соотнесенность с другими событиями или обозначена их временная последовательность.

Сравнить:

*Храм построен в XIX веке французскими архитекторами.* Далее — описание храма.

*Храм был построен  французскими архитекторами в XIX веке, но уже полвека спустя  его значительно перестроили.*

Comment: Я тут подумал. А вам не кажется, что указания времени постройки «в XIX веке» при настоящем времени сказуемого «построен» вообще быть не может и возможно только указание производителя: *Храм построен французскими архитекторами*?

Comment: То есть среди указанных вами «деталей строительства» при настоящем времени сказуемого допустимо только указание производителя, места, используемого материала, орудия/средства.

Comment: Вы наберите в Нацкорпусе сочетание "храм построен" и посмотрите, в каких предложениях оно используется. Сравните с сочетанием "храм был построен". Тогда сами можете сделать вывод.

Comment: Набрал, есть предложения с «храм построен» и указанием времени, но это может быть и неграмотность российских журналистов. Поэтому интересно ваше мнение насчёт того, что я изложил в комментариях выше.

Comment: К вопросу появились новые ответы и комментарии. Ознакомьтесь, они во многом проливают свет на тему.